# How to use Nested dict to replace string in other column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary like below and I would like to replace string using inner key value pair if that key is at the end of string, replace it with value only when the country Code equals to dict key (not inner key)

```
'IND': {' PVT. LTD.': ' Pvt. Ltd.',
 ' pvt. Ltd': ' Pvt. Ltd.',
 ' PVT LTD': ' Pvt. Ltd.',
 ' L.L.P.': ' LLP',
 ' LTD.': ' Ltd.',
 ' LLP.': ' LLP',
 ' ltd': ' Ltd.',
 ' llp': ' LLP'},
 'GBR': {' P.L.C.': ' PLC',
 ' C.I.C.': ' CIC',
 ' p.l.c': ' PLC',
 ' c.i.c': ' CIC',
 ' s.e.': ' SE',
 ' PLC.': ' PLC'},
 'USA': {' LTD. CO.': ' Ltd. Co.',
 ' L.L.L.P.': ' LLLP',
 ' ltd. Co': ' Ltd. Co.',
 ' l.l.l.p': ' LLLP',
 ' L.L.P.': ' LLP',
 ' L.L.C.': ' LLC',
 ' l.l.p': ' LLP',
 ' l.l.c': ' LLC'}
```

My dataframe has two cols. Legal name and Reg Country Code -

| Name | Reg Country Code |
| --- | --- |
| NexPoint LTD. CO. | USA |
| Silverplay P.L.C. | GBR |
| ALLOYS PVT. LTD. | IND |
| GALLIUM ltd. | IND |
| ELLIOTT s.e. | GBR |

I used below code - it is replacing the string as and when the legal name finds the inner key but not checking the country condition with outer key. Can someone pl suggest me. (I have a big list)

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    for k1 in country_dict.items():
        if df.loc[i, 'Reg Country Code'] == k1:
            for k2, v2 in country_dict[k1].items():
                df.loc[df['Reg Country Code'] == k1, 'Name'] = [re.sub(k2, v, x) if x.endswith(k2) else x for x in df.loc[df['Reg Country Code'] == k1, 'Name']]
```

My Output should be:

| Name | Reg Country Code |
| --- | --- |
| NexPoint Ltd. Co. | USA |
| Silverplay PLC | GBR |
| ALLOYS Pvt. Ltd. | IND |
| GALLIUM Ltd. | IND |
| ELLIOTT SE | GBR |

Comment: What is `df`? What is `country_dict`? Could you please provide executable sample data for a fully working minimal example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group the df by country code and replace

```
df['NAME'] = df.groupby('REG COUNTRY CODE')['NAME'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(d[x.name], regex = True))

    NAME                REG COUNTRY CODE
0   NexPoint Ltd. Co.   USA
1   Silverplay PLC      GBR
2   ALLOYS Pvt. Ltd.    IND
3   GALLIUM Ltd..       IND
4   ELLIOTT SE          GBR
```

Explanation:

- df.groupby('REG COUNTRY CODE').name returns name of the group (country code in this case).
- By using d[x.name], we are able to access the value dictionary corresponding to dictionary keys (country codes)
- Setting regex to True helps us replace the string partially

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: @Vaishali

Thanks for your quick reply. This is not working for me. What is d[x.name] here.   Aren't we using dictionary to decide which key pair to be used for replacement? 

I mean 1st layer dictionary key to decide the country and 2nd layer key to check if existed in name and then replace with value if found? Sorry if I am sounding naive.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/6287308/vaishali

Comment: @user14613954, added some explanation. Not working means what is the issue?

Comment: I can jump in here, so `d` is your dictionary in this case: `d = {'IND': {' PVT. LTD.': ' Pvt. Ltd.', ' pvt. Ltd': ' Pvt. Ltd.',...`. You will have to assign your dictionary the variable name `d` for this to work.

Comment: @Vaishali

This seems handy to me but It is replacing the inside string as well. I want endswith to be replaced. Here are some example where Code resulted as below: 371 EAST PACES, LLC changed to 371 EAST PCS, LLC HILL COUNTRY CHRISTIAN SCHOOL changed to HILL CoNTRY CHRISTIAN SCHOOL ABC COLLIN na changed to ABC CoLIN NA


-- pl suggest

Comment: You can use replace on partial string rather than full string. I can look at the code if you update your example df with the cases where the above code fails. That said, there might be a completely different way to address this problem. Instead of dictionary, you can use general string cleaning (I don't know the full logic that you require but something like remove dots and capitalize or convert words like PVT to title case etc)

Comment: @Vaishali  In my inner dictionary key, I prefixed backslash \ to escape chars like .(){}[]* etc. and suffixed $ to each inner key so that it searches the end of the string. Works fine as of now.